# Question regarding power series in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

> Fix $a,b,c\in\mathbb{C}$, $c$ not an integer. Show that there is a
> unique analytic function $F$ in the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$ such that
> $F(0)=1$ and$$z(1-z)F''(z)+(c-(a+b+1)z)F'(z)-abF(z)=0$$ for all
> $z\in\mathbb{D}$. [Hint: find a recursion for the power series
> coefficients]

I can only think of letting $F=\sum\limits^{\infty}_{0}a_nz^n$ with $a_0=1$. After computing this into the formula, I get a complicated equation, and I'm not sure how to proceed from there to prove existence and uniqueness. Also by letting $F$ be such a power series, I am already assuming that $F$ is analytic on $z=0$.

Another approach is that maybe I need some explicit formula for $F$ and use the analytic continuation. Could you give me any suggestion?

Comment: These are hypergeometric functions, so they have an easy expansion in terms of the Pochhammer symbols of $a,b,c$ - check hypergeometric differential equation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function

Comment: Thank you. I read the part about hypergeometric differential equation but I'm still unsure how to approach this problem

Comment: show that the power series with the coefficients indicated in the link, namely $\frac{(a)_n(b)_n}{n!(c)_n}$, works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This differential equation has a regular singular point at $0$ with indicial equation $r^2 + (c-1) r = 0$, so at least if $c$ is not an integer, there should be a solution that is a power series.  If you plug in $F(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ to the differential equation and look at the coefficient of $z^n$ in the result, you should
get a recurrence for $a_{n+1}$ as a function of $a_n$.  The Ratio Test will confirm
that the radius of convergence is $1$.